# Can't access values of Laravel's JSON response object

Tags: php, json, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.1

This might be one of the strangest bugs I've encountered.

In my controller, when a user makes a reply (through AJAX), I return a JSON response in an attempt to get the ID of that reply.

```
$reply = Status::create([
    'body' => $replyText,
])->user()->associate(Auth::user());

$status->replies()->save($reply);

$replyID = $reply->id;

return response()->json([
    'replyID ' => $replyID
]);
```

This works fine. I get a JSON reponse with what I asked for. Great.

[image]

Now here's the problem. For WHATEVER reason, I can't access the values of the object JSON is returning.

```
x = response.replyID;
console.log(x);
```

or

```
x = response["replyID"];
console.log(x);
```

or any variation of that will ALWAYS returned `undefined`.

To illustrate how stupid this is, let me demonstrate with the following:

```
success: function(response) {
    myObj = { "age":30 };
    console.log(response);
    console.log(myObj);
    x = myObj.age;
    y = response.replyID;
    console.log(x); 
    console.log(y);             
},
```

This returns:

[image]

What could POSSIBLY be causing this?

Comment: have you tried to use x = JSON.parse(response);
then use it to `x.replyID`

Comment: Just tried it. It returns the error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: I'm not pretty sure how to do it on laravel as you are using the `json->` but on pure PHP I manage to get it working using `json_encode` then parse it on the *success* callback. This is very confusing since your response returns with no errors.

Comment: Try this JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response)) and share o/p of console.log(JSON.stringify(response))

Comment: console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response))); returns the same thing as console.log(response);.

Comment: Can you set `dataType:'json'` in your `$.ajax` request & check

Comment: I've added dataType: "json" to the ajax request. Not sure what you mean by adding it to check. 

It still returns undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have extra blank space `'replyID '` here remove this

```
return response()->json([
   'replyID' => $replyID
]);
```

Before applying this if you tried like this it would work

```
x = response["replyID "];
console.log(x);
```

But now, I think you understand the problem came from one blank space.

Comment: You're my hero. Don't forget that.